# Check for table corruption

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I monitor MySQL databases by querying various things remotely. I recently came across an issue where by a table had become corrupted but I did not know about it until the daily mysqldump failed. Is there a way I can check for corruption (without running a CHECK TABLE on every table)? I thought I had it figured when I noticed information_schema.tables has a table_comment column which says this when it's corrupt:

```
TABLE_COMMENT: Table './demo/test' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

Turns out, when I try to search on that column, i.e. WHERE TABLE_COMMENT LIKE '%marked as crashed%', nothing is returned!

I need to be able to query this from a stored procedure, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS;
and then run 
show warnings;
```

will show you what all tables are corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

When you issue

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS;
```

On the database in question, corrupted tables will be shown. They will have no row count or size, most of the properties will be null, and in `Comment` column you will see your text:

> Table './demo/test' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Comment: That's for the suggestion but that is based on information_schema.tables so I still have the same issue.

Comment: I am not sure I follow?

Comment: This shows all tables, not the corrupted tables.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Yeah but those that are crashed are clearly visible, as explained

Answer (score 2):

Usually a table that is corrupt will halt a mysqldump in its tracks. A very quick-and-dirty way to check for table corruption across all tables is to mysqldump the table schemas with no data:

```
mysqldump --no-data --all-databases > table_schema.sql
```

Go to the Last Line of the `table_schema.sql`. You can look for this pattern:

```
-- Dump completed on 2013-12-26  8:56:27
```

If you see `Dump completed on`, all the tables are fine. Otherwise, the mysqldump should halt at or before the corrupt table.

**CAUTION**: Doing mysqldump on a corrupt MyISAM table will halt the `mysqldump`. Doing mysqldump on a corrupt InnoDB table could crash mysqld.

In all honesty, the database needs to have `REPAIR TABLE` done periodically (at least once a month)

Comment: There is three hyphen in ```no-data``` :-)